# neo4j websocket connection failure

Tags: docker, neo4j, websocket

I am having error like on screenshot below:
[image]

I was searching a bit but suggestions are mainly about this solution here:
https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/
which doesnt work for me.
I am running this in docker and service definition is just this:

```
db:
        container_name: neo4j
        image: neo4j:3.2
        ports:
             - "7474:7474"
```

The web console error says just that "cannot establish connection to server  ws://localhost:7474" .
The docker logs says that bolt has been enabled.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to map the bolt port `7687` as well

```
db:
        container_name: neo4j
        image: neo4j:3.2
        ports:
             - "7474:7474"             
             - "7687:7687"
```

Comment: yes, completely haven't thought of this. Works, thank you